# How to pass array values to controller for validation?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, codeigniter, validation

I am trying to pass the values of form inputs to a controller for validation.  The values are populated in the view using an array.  The problem is that I don't know how to get the necessary 'name' values from the array for the individual inputs in order to pass them through validation.

In the first view the form inputs are described this way:

```
<?php echo form_checkbox('study_items[]', 'Medical History', FALSE); 
    echo form_label('Medical History', 'Medical History');?>
    <br>
    <?php echo form_checkbox('study_items[]', 'Physical Exam', FALSE); 
    echo form_label('Physical Exam', 'Physical Exam');?>
    <br>
    <?php echo form_checkbox('study_items[]', 'Clinical Assessment', FALSE); 
    echo form_label('Clinical Assessment', 'Clinical Assessment');?>
```

The user only has to check the item(s) that apply to their specific need.  This is submitted to the validation controller which, after successful validation, ONLY sends those items that were selected back to a view in an array like so:

```
$data['si_items'] = $this->input->post('study_items');
```

In the next view, the code for a sample input looks like this:

```
    <?php foreach ($si_items as $si_item) {


        echo $si_item. ' '. "$";

        $data001 = array(

              'name'        => $si_item,
                  'id'          => $si_item,
                  'value'       => '',
                  'maxlength'   => '10',
                  'size'        => '50',
                  'style'       => 'width:100px',

        );

        echo form_input($data001);
        echo '<br>';    
    }

 ?>
```

and allows the user to enter a dollar amount for the items they selected to fit their need on the previous page.

As sample output of this portion of the code looks like this:

"Medical History $**_______________**"
"Physical Exam $**_______________**"
"Clinical Assessment $**_______________**"

where the blank is a textbox for entering the price of each item.  So far, this all works perfectly to display each form input box and labels checked by the user in the previous view.

However, I'm at a loss as to how to get the 'name' for each individual input in order to validate it.  The validation controller does not recognize '$si_items' as a name value.  This has  me stumped and there HAS to be a way to do this.

In my validation controller I want to check that each entry has a decimal value (i.e. 234.56) as the user's input.

Any ideas?  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

we are missing swaths of code, but from what you have shown;\

```
$data['si_items'] = $this->input->post('study_items');
```

is the assignment of your study items (which is an array), meaning that the call in your foreach should not be

```
foreach ($si_items as $si_item) {
```

but rather

```
foreach ($data['si_items'] as $si_item) {
```

that or change your initial assignment to the following;

```
$si_items = $this->input->post('study_items');
```

Comment: Yes, I did leave out quite a bit of code because there is a lot.  I thought I gave a good idea of what I was trying to do and what I have already.  Is there anything I could add that would make things clearer?  Thanks.

Comment: perhaps some examples of the output of the line `echo $si_item. ' '. "$";`

Comment: if that isn't doing what you want, `print_r($si_items)` just before the foreach and show us that

Comment: Ok.  I edited the original question to show the output I get when I foreach through the array.  Again, that part works with no problem as is.

Comment: assuming the form when displayed has the correct names as the field names/id...  are you asking how to get the values and loop through them to validate after they submit the form?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes that is what I am trying to do.

Typically, I would go to the validation controller and so something like this:

'$this->form_validation->set_rules('medical_history', 'Medical History', 'decimal');'

But, in this case, I don't know the correct method to get each 'name' attribute of the form values that are populated by the array.

This doesn't work:

'$this->form_validation->set_rules($si_items, 'Medical History', 'decimal');'

Comment: Typically, I would go to the validation controller and so something like this:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('medical_history', 'Medical History', 'decimal');`

But, in this case, I don't know the correct method to get each 'name' attribute of the form values that are populated by the array.

This doesn't work:

`$this->form_validation->set_rules($si_items, 'Medical History', 'decimal');`

Comment: loop through `$_POST` on the receiving page to get all the post fields and their values, such as `foreach($_POST as $key => $value)` which will allow you to see all of them, but you may want to rename them so it is easier to identify the ones you want

Comment: Ah...  well they are not coming from the form as `$si_items` but rather the individual field names.  perhaps if we saw the validator code?

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I'm trying to figure out.  I don't know how to write the appropriate code to evaluate the user input from here.